# Rewrite rule for "site down" pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, maintenance-mode

I was trying to install this .htaccess to notify my users of site maintenance. It seems the first [L] isn't working and the second rewrite is doing everything.

How do you guys do site maintenance messages?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^s/down$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://metaward.com/s/down [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work (but I have to set the status code in PHP)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/.*$
RewriteRule .* down.php [L]
```

and in down.php

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable',true,503);
?>
```

Any problems with this? My main concerns are what user's see (which is why i keep static content) and what search engines see (the 503 status code).

Comment: This is what I settled on, but `RewriteCond`s are not needed. In this case
`RewriteRule !^/(?:static|media)/ down.php [L]`
will do.

Answer (score 6):

You don’t need to an external redirect. Just send the [503 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) and your error document.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /503.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
```

But you need Apache 2.x to use a different status code with the R flag other than 3xx.

Comment: 503 won't actually cause the browser to redirect.

Comment: @Paul Tarjan: I’ve never said that. Apache 2 just extended the use of the `R` flag for setting status codes. Only 3xx status codes will actually cause an external redirect.

Comment: Setting [R=503] shows a default apache page not the one I specified in my RewriteRule. Is this the expected response?

Comment: Add "ErrorDocument 503 /down/index.html" to facility custom 503 message. Add "Alias /down /var/somewere/down" to share message page

Comment: _ErrorDocument_, not _RewriteDocument_.

Answer (score 1):

The RewriteRules I'm using on my website when I want to shut it down for maintenance are these ones :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=MY_IP_ADDRESS
RewriteRule    ^$  /down.html  [L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=MY_IP_ADDRESS
RewriteRule    [^/down.html$]  /down.html  [L]
```

*(Maybe not quite "optimized", I should say... But it worked (or so it seemed) each time I used those)*

Everything but down.html gets redirected to down.html -- except for me, of course : I want to be able to test the maintenance operations I'm doing, obviously

ANd when I'm finished, I just comment those four lines.

Comment: The IP address condition: neat.

Comment: won't that make search engines index your page as if it was perfectly up but serving your weird down page?

Comment: @Paul : I have to admit I don't know for sure ; I've put <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" /> in down.html as a security measure, but I'm not sure what a bot would do : I've never seen the content of my down.html page on google, that's for sure, and I've never noticed anything "bad" for the other pages ;; but my maintenance operations are rare, and never lasted more than 3 hours ;; and my website is not big/famous, so not indexed too often...  ;; Still, if someone sees a way to make this better, I'm definitly interested (would be nice to provide an answer, and get one myself !) ;-)

Comment: You should add the [R=503] status to the RewriteRule to signify a temporary maintenance condition.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels: [R=503] doesn't work on my Apache, because it requires `ErrorDocument 503` directive. With `ErrorDocument` Apache behaves a little differently to what was suggested above, by redirecting user to `down.html` rather than just showing down.html for any request.

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache as a proxy for a ruby on rails application.

The only thing I had to do was add

```
ProxyPass /custom-errors !
ErrorDocument 503 /custom-errors/maintenance-message.html
```

To my httpd.conf and make sure that : [Apache installation]/htdocs/custom-errors/maintenance-message.html exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone using the Retry-After header. I've read (but don't have the link anymore as I read it a while ago) that you should use a 503 in combo with a Retry-After n (n = number of seconds to try again in; 3600 is an hour) header. If you use the 503 and the Retry-After in combo, especially on your robots.txt/sitemap it should not mess with links and page rank for SEO if you don't leave it like that for a long time.